# Creating Charts (from Template) using Loop in VBA

Tags: vba, excel, loops

I'm trying to create multiple charts for each of the row I have in my spreadsheet. I have managed to be able to create a loop but I'm stuck on how to change the source of data for the corresponding selected row for the new chart.

```
Sub Macro6()

    Range("B2").Select
    ActiveCell.Range("A1:I1").Select
    ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart2(201, xlColumnClustered).Select
    ActiveChart.ApplyChartTemplate ( _
        "C:\Users\arboari\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Templates\Charts\Education.crtx")
    ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Range("'Master Sheet'!$B$2:$J$2")
    ActiveChart.Parent.Cut
    Sheets("Charts").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Sheets("Master Sheet").Select
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Range("A1:I1").Select

    For Counter = 1 To 10
        ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart2(201, xlColumnClustered).Select
        ActiveChart.ApplyChartTemplate ( _
            "C:\Users\arboari\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Templates\Charts\Education.crtx")
        **ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Range("'Master Sheet'!$B$2:$J$2")**
        ActiveChart.Parent.Cut
        Sheets("Charts").Select
        ActiveSheet.Paste
        Sheets("Charts").Select
        Sheets("Master Sheet").Select
        ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Range("A1:I1").Select
    Next Counter

End Sub
```

The line in between the asterisks is what I'm trying to make relative since its absolute thus making the new graph's data source always the B2-J2 line.

Thanks!

Comment: What rows are you trying to create the charts for? 2-11?

Comment: I'm guessing you're trying for something like `ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Range("'Master Sheet'!$B$" & Counter & ":$J$" & Counter)`

Comment: @dwirony yes Rows 2-11. I tried the the line you provided and its not working. the data source for the 2nd and on graphs keep getting its data from B2:J2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just used this and it worked fine. However you definitely want to work to remove all the `ActiveSheet`s, `Select`s and `Cut`/`Paste` from this.

```
Sub Macro6()

    ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart2(201, xlColumnClustered).Select
    ActiveChart.ApplyChartTemplate ( _
        "C:\Users\arboari\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Templates\Charts\Education.crtx")
    ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Range("'Master Sheet'!$B$2:$J$2")
    ActiveChart.Parent.Cut
    Sheets("Charts").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Sheets("Master Sheet").Select
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Range("A1:I1").Select

    For counter = 1 To 10
        ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart2(201, xlColumnClustered).Select
        ActiveChart.ApplyChartTemplate ( _
            "C:\Users\arboari\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Templates\Charts\Education.crtx")
        ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Range("'Master Sheet'!$B$" & counter & ":$J$" & counter)
        ActiveChart.Parent.Cut
        Sheets("Charts").Select
        ActiveSheet.Paste
        Sheets("Charts").Select
        Sheets("Master Sheet").Select
        ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Range("A1:I1").Select
    Next counter

End Sub
```

Comment: i just ran it again. it finally worked. Thanks so much!! I really appreciate the help.